# Cleaner way of appending data to List in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I've been experimenting various way to get data from different variety of website; as such, between the use of JSON or BeautifulSoup. Currently, I have written a scraper to collect data such as `[{Title,Description,Replies,Topic_Starter, Total_Views}]`; but it pretty much has no reusable code. I've been figuring out how to correct my approach of appending data to one singular list for simplicity and reusability. But I've pretty much hit a stone with my current capability.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep


url = 'https://forum.lowyat.net/ReviewsandGuides'

list_topic = []
list_description = []
list_replies = []
list_topicStarted = []
list_totalViews = []


def getContentFromURL(_url):
    try:
        response = get(_url)
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        return html_soup
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error.getContentFromURL:', e)
        return None


def iterateThroughPages(_lastindexpost, _postperpage, _url):
    indices = '/+'
    index = 0
    for i in range(index, _lastindexpost):
        print('Getting data from ' + url)
        try:
            extractDataFromRow1(getContentFromURL(_url))
            extractDataFromRow2(getContentFromURL(_url))
            print('current page index is: ' + str(index))
            print(_url)
            while i <= _lastindexpost:
                for table in get(_url):
                    if table != None:
                        new_getPostPerPage = i + _postperpage
                        newlink = f'{url}{indices}{new_getPostPerPage}'
                        print(newlink)
                        bs_link = getContentFromURL(newlink)
                        extractDataFromRow1(bs_link)
                        extractDataFromRow2(bs_link)
                        # threading to prevent spam. Waits 0.5 secs before executing
                        sleep(0.5)
                    i += _postperpage
                    print('current page index is: ' + str(i))
                    if i > _lastindexpost:
                        # If i gets more than the input page(etc 1770) halts
                        print('No more available post to retrieve')
                        return
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error.iterateThroughPages:', e)
            return None


def extractDataFromRow1(_url):
    try:
        for container in _url.find_all('td', {'class': 'row1', 'valign': 'middle'}):
            # get data from topic title in table cell
            topic = container.select_one(
                'a[href^="/topic/"]').text.replace("\n", "")
            description = container.select_one(
                'div.desc').text.replace("\n", "")
            if topic or description is not None:
                dict_topic = topic
                dict_description = description
                if dict_description is '':
                    dict_description = 'No Data'
                    # list_description.append(dict_description)
                    #so no empty string#
                list_topic.append(dict_topic)
                list_description.append(dict_description)
            else:
                None
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error.extractDataFromRow1:', e)
        return None


def extractDataFromRow2(_url):
    try:
        for container in _url.select('table[cellspacing="1"] > tr')[2:32]:
            replies = container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip()
            topic_started = container.select_one(
                'td:nth-of-type(5)').text.strip()
            total_views = container.select_one(
                'td:nth-of-type(6)').text.strip()
            if replies or topic_started or total_views is not None:
                dict_replies = replies
                dict_topicStarted = topic_started
                dict_totalViews = total_views
                if dict_replies is '':
                    dict_replies = 'No Data'
                elif dict_topicStarted is '':
                    dict_topicStarted = 'No Data'
                elif dict_totalViews is '':
                    dict_totalViews = 'No Data'
                list_replies.append(dict_replies)
                list_topicStarted.append(dict_topicStarted)
                list_totalViews.append(dict_totalViews)
            else:
                print('no data')
                None
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error.extractDataFromRow2:', e)
        return None


# limit to 1740
print(iterateThroughPages(1740, 30, url))
new_panda = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Title': list_topic, 'Description': list_description,
     'Replies': list_replies, 'Topic Starter': list_topicStarted, 'Total Views': list_totalViews})
print(new_panda)
```

I'm sure the use of my `try` is redundant at this point as well, my large variety of List including, and the use of `While` and `For` is most likely practiced wrongly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would separate the two concerns of getting the table data and processing it a bit more. For this it might make sense to have one generator that just yields rows from the table and gets the next page if needed:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

SESSION = requests.Session()

def get_table_rows(base_url, posts_per_page=30):
    """Continously yield rows from the posts table.

    Requests a new page only when needed.
    """
    start_at = 0
    while True:
        print(f'current page index is: {start_at // posts_per_page + 1}')
        response = SESSION.get(base_url + f"/+{start_at}")
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml',
                             parse_only=SoupStrainer("table", {"cellspacing": "1"}))
        yield from soup.find_all("tr")
        start_at += posts_per_page
```

This already chooses only the correct table, but still contains the header row. It also reuses the connection to the server by using a [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). This is an infinite generator. Choosing to only get the first n entries is done later using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Now we just need to parse a single table row, which can go to another function:

```
def parse_row(row):
    """Get info from a row"""
    columns = row.select("td")
    try:
        if not columns or columns[0]["class"] in (["darkrow1"], ["nopad"]):
            return
    except KeyError:  # first column has no class
        # print(row)
        return
    try:
        title = row.select_one("td.row1 a[href^=/topic/]").text.strip() or "No Data"
        description = row.select_one("td.row1 div.desc").text.strip() or "No Data"
        replies = row.select_one("td:nth-of-type(4)").text.strip() or "No Data"
        topic_starter = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(5)').text.strip() or "No Data"
        total_views = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(6)').text.strip() or "No Data"
    except AttributeError:  # something is None
        # print(row)
        return
    return {"Title": title,
            "Description": description,
            "Replies": replies,
            "Topic Starter": topic_starter,
            "Total Views": total_views}

def parse_rows(url):
    """Filter out rows that could not be parsed"""
    yield from filter(None, (parse_row(row) for row in get_table_rows(url)))
```

Then your main loop just becomes this:

```
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://forum.lowyat.net/ReviewsandGuides'
    max_posts = 1740
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(islice(parse_rows(url), max_posts))
    print(df)
```

Note that I (mostly) followed Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especially when naming variables (`lower_case`). This code also has a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script from another script and the functions have (probably too short) [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing what each function does.

Comment: after hitting index 53; the response becomes a `<Response [403]>` and goes into an infinite loop; while all previous ones before index 53 are `200`, am I understanding the concept wrongly atm ~? Does the page index through each row one by one or is it indexing each page~? Sorry that I'm asking more when you've taken the time to help and explain many of them. I'm trying to understand most of them, using the referral you've given but at the same time I'm having that return output.

Comment: oh; I realized what happened. I got IP blocked from the site for requesting too often.

Comment: After adding threading to prevent spam; it worked beautifully~ thank you so much

Comment: @Minial I added `response.raise_for_status()` so at least it dies with an exception in that case instead of being stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Ah, alright ~ but i had to thread it to avoid being blocked from the site.

Comment: @Minial Yeah that is probably the real solution to that problem, but not being stuck in an infinite loop is nice in addition :-).

Comment: Yup; once it reaches the end post it stops~ but regardless; thanks for your time and effort :) much appreciation in helping me improve my coding; I've pretty much applied to my other methods and reduced lots of unnecessary and repetitive for loops after understanding how yours worked.