# Webcrawler for a car forum

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've been experimenting more with webcrawling and hence have started to get a better understanding compared to my previous questions. Right now, my code scraps from a car forum on each page and iterates through every pages. What would you recommend to improve on?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import pandas as pd

list_topic = []
list_time = []

SESSION = requests.Session()


def get_response(url):  # Gets the <html> structure from the website #
    response = SESSION.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml',
                         parse_only=SoupStrainer('ul', {'class': 'posts posts-archive'}))
    return soup


def iteration(url, max_page=52):
    starting_page = 1
    while starting_page <= max_page:
        ## formats the new URL etc (https://paultan.org/topics/test-drive-reviews/page/1) ##
        new_url = url + f"page/{starting_page}"
        data = get_response(new_url)
        get_reviews(data)
        ## iteration starts ##
        starting_page += 1


def get_reviews(response):
    for container in response('article'):
        title = container.h2.a.text
        time = container.time.text
        list_topic.append(title)
        list_time.append(time)
    else:
        None


def create_pdReview():
    return pd.DataFrame({'Title': list_topic, 'Time': list_time})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    URL = 'https://paultan.org/topics/test-drive-reviews/'
    print(iteration(URL))
    print(create_pdReview())
```

I've been wondering; would using `yield` improve the efficiency and simplicity of the code? How would it be done? Because I've been trying to learn from my previous inquiries that has been answered on earlier. Here is a [similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211238/cleaner-way-of-appending-data-to-list-in-beautifulsoup) and I'm trying to put to practice what has been recommended so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are discussing performance of a particular piece of code, it's important to recognize bottlenecks and major contributors to the runtime of the program.

In your particular case, even though you've applied some optimizations like `SoupStrainer` speed-up for HTML parsing, the *synchronous nature of the script* is the biggest problem by far. The script is processing pages one by one, not getting to the next page until the processing for the current page is finished.

Switching to an asynchronous approach would be the natural next step in your optimizations. Look into using third-party frameworks like [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) or, if you are adventurous, things like `asyncio` or `grequests`.

---

You could apply one more optimization to your current script which should help you optimize the "crawling/scraping" part - instead of using `requests.get()`, initialize `session = requests.Session()` and use `session.get()` to make requests ([documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)). This would allow the underlying TCP connection to be re-used for subsequent requests resulting in a performance increase.

Comment: I've changed the way of iteration; but it looks like an honest mess at the moment. I've used Session as you've recommended ~ but at the moment I'm trying to think how to simplify and get it to work with my previous version =l.

Comment: @Minial I usually use a class and store `session` as an instance attribute which is initialized in a class constructor.